# Firebase demographics page - numbers showing up in place of city name

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

on my Firebase demographics page - numbers are showing up in place of city name.

For example, 59139 is showing up in the Town/City column when I select Brazil. Many such numbers are being shown.